# How to extract occurances of specific field from txt file using linux command line?

Tags: linux

I used this command (cut -d ":" -f1 /home/linuxuser/accesslog.txt) to extract the content of the file, I got this output shown in this picture [image]

I want to know how to extract occurances of ipaddress “198.46.149.143” using linux command line.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to pipe and grep the output of your command?

```bash
cut -d ":" -f1 /home/linuxuser/accesslog.txt | grep “198.46.149.143”
# and if you want to count the number of occurences:
cut -d ":" -f1 /home/linuxuser/accesslog.txt | grep “198.46.149.143” | wc -l
```